# Buttons and Processes?

Tags: orbeon

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner:-Buttons-and-Processes) on buttons and processes, and I'd like to implement it. Unfortunately I don't know much about xforms, and even less about Orbeon forms, so the documentation seems to leave out the most crucial piece of information: where do you put the xml that they're describing to create buttons and processes? Is it necessary to compile everything from source, or can the buttons be added to the xml of the form...?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile. Processes go into property files, specifically into `properties-local.xml`. See the [documentation here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties). I updated the documentation.